# tabularx table formats poorly when too long

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

I have a long, multi-columned tabularx table in a document I'm working with. I'm finding that under certain circumstances the table's formatting breaks.

My minimum working example (works with the commented lines, breaks when they're uncommented):

```
\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=10pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{.5cm}p{.5cm}p{.5cm}p{.5cm}p{.75cm}p{8.75cm}}
    \multicolumn{6}{p{11cm}}{\textbf{A Heading}} \\

    1     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Foo} \\
    & 1.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consequetum in farfarbar foobraz do congraftsh thing stuff wrap need enough to make you wrap} \\
    2     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Bar} \\
    & 2.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{More lorem ipsum, or stuff with numbers, that doesn't quite wrap as far end} \\
    &       & 2.1.1 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Random words words and more words in a fairly long line} \\
    &       & 2.1.2 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Other random words in a line} \\
    1     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Foo} \\
    & 1.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consequetum in farfarbar foobraz do congraftsh thing stuff wrap need enough to make you wrap} \\
    2     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Bar} \\
    & 2.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{More lorem ipsum, or stuff with numbers, that doesn't quite wrap as far end} \\
    &       & 2.1.1 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Random words words and more words in a fairly long line} \\
    &       & 2.1.2 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Other random words in a line} \\
    1     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Foo} \\
    & 1.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consequetum in farfarbar foobraz do congraftsh thing stuff wrap need enough to make you wrap} \\
    2     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Bar} \\
    & 2.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{More lorem ipsum, or stuff with numbers, that doesn't quite wrap as far end} \\
    &       & 2.1.1 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Random words words and more words in a fairly long line} \\
    &       & 2.1.2 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Other random words in a line} \\
    1     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Foo} \\
    & 1.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consequetum in farfarbar foobraz do congraftsh thing stuff wrap need enough to make you wrap} \\
    2     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Bar} \\
    & 2.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{More lorem ipsum, or stuff with numbers, that doesn't quite wrap as far end} \\
    &       & 2.1.1 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Random words words and more words in a fairly long line} \\
    &       & 2.1.2 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Other random words in a line} \\
    1     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Foo} \\
    & 1.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consequetum in farfarbar foobraz do congraftsh thing stuff wrap need enough to make you wrap} \\
    2     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Bar} \\
    & 2.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{More lorem ipsum, or stuff with numbers, that doesn't quite wrap as far end} \\
    &       & 2.1.1 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Random words words and more words in a fairly long line} \\
    &       & 2.1.2 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Other random words in a line} \\
    1     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Foo} \\
    & 1.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consequetum in farfarbar foobraz do congraftsh thing stuff wrap need enough to make you wrap} \\
    2     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Bar} \\
    & 2.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{More lorem ipsum, or stuff with numbers, that doesn't quite wrap as far end} \\
    &       & 2.1.1 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Random words words and more words in a fairly long line} \\
    &       & 2.1.2 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Other random words in a line} \\
    1     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Foo} \\
    & 1.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consequetum in farfarbar foobraz do congraftsh thing stuff wrap need enough to make you wrap} \\
    2     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Bar} \\
    & 2.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{More lorem ipsum, or stuff with numbers, that doesn't quite wrap as far end} \\
    &       & 2.1.1 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Random words words and more words in a fairly long line} \\
    &       & 2.1.2 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Other random words in a line} \\
    %1     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Foo} \\
    %& 1.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consequetum in farfarbar foobraz do congraftsh thing stuff wrap need enough to make you wrap} \\
    %2     & \multicolumn{5}{X}{Bar} \\
    %& 2.1   & \multicolumn{4}{X}{More lorem ipsum, or stuff with numbers, that doesn't quite wrap as far end} \\
    %&       & 2.1.1 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Random words words and more words in a fairly long line} \\
    %&       & 2.1.2 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Other random words in a line} \\

 \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The formatting when not broken (only the first page):

[image: not broken]

The formatting when broken; i.e., when the document lines are uncommented (only the first page):

[image: broken]

The log file from building it:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.7.5)  25 JUL 2016 14:55
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**document.tex
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2016/02/24 3.9q The Babel package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2016/02/24 3.9q Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
Package: tabularx 2014/10/28 v2.10 `tabularx' package (DPC)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen104
\extrarowheight=\dimen105
\NC@list=\toks14
\extratabsurround=\skip43
\backup@length=\skip44
)
\TX@col@width=\dimen106
\TX@old@table=\dimen107
\TX@old@col=\dimen108
\TX@target=\dimen109
\TX@delta=\dimen110
\TX@cols=\count88
\TX@ftn=\toks15
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ltablex/ltablex.sty
Package: ltablex 2014/08/13 v1.1 Modified tabularx

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip45
\LTright=\skip46
\LTpre=\skip47
\LTpost=\skip48
\LTchunksize=\count89
\LTcapwidth=\dimen111
\LT@head=\box26
\LT@firsthead=\box27
\LT@foot=\box28
\LT@lastfoot=\box29
\LT@cols=\count90
\LT@rows=\count91
\c@LT@tables=\count92
\c@LT@chunks=\count93
\LT@p@ftn=\toks16
))

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [paper=letter,fontsize=10pt].

(./document.aux)
\openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.

Overfull \hbox (6.32925pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 63--63
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2.1.1|
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.32925pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 63--63
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2.1.2|
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.32925pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 63--63
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2.1.1|
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.32925pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 63--63
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2.1.2|
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.32925pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 63--63
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2.1.1|
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.32925pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 63--63
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2.1.2|
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.32925pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 63--63
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2.1.1|
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.32925pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 63--63
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2.1.2|
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.32925pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 63--63
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2.1.1|
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.32925pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 63--63
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2.1.2|
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.32925pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 63--63
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2.1.1|
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.32925pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 63--63
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2.1.2|
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.32925pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 63--63
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2.1.1|
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.32925pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 63--63
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2.1.2|
 []

[1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] (./document.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   babel.sty    2016/02/24 3.9q The Babel package
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
tabularx.sty    2014/10/28 v2.10 `tabularx' package (DPC)
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
 ltablex.sty    2014/08/13 v1.1 Modified tabularx
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
 ***********

 )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 823 strings out of 493029
 10008 string characters out of 6136235
 118871 words of memory out of 5000000
 4418 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3948 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,8n,23p,181b,263s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></us
r/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on document.pdf (2 pages, 28961 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 19 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 12 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

A couple of notes:

- We're fairly set on the formatting of the table's lines, since in its actual usage this is a very long table exported from Excel, and the less editing we have to do to it the better
- This problem isn't correlated with the use of `ltablex`; without that package, the table will exhibit the same symptoms except it extends from the end of the page
- I can fix this problem by downgrading `tabularx` to version 2.07. I'm reluctant to use this as a long-term solution, however, since I don't want to use a 17-year-old version of this package.
- Though I only show the first pages of output, in both the broken and working cases the table spans multiple pages

Comment: I do find quite daring that you use X-columns in \multicolumns of different width. Why don't you use longtable + a calculated width instead?

Comment: you have fixed width columns `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{.5cm}p{.5cm}p{.5cm}p{.5cm}p{.75cm}p{8.75cm}}` so tabularx can do nothing useful and has no way to make the table the specified width. Just use longtable here

Comment: Will your labels be systematically periodic?

Comment: @Bernard, the tables won't be systematically periodic. It's just like that here since I couldn't put in the actual filler

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'll give that a shot. I was playing with various different column-width specifications, and didn't leave the variable column setting in (I had it in the last column)

Comment: You all are correct, it makes a lot of sense to just use fixed width columns. Thanks!

Comment: My idea was that nested list environments would fit much better (customised with `enumitem`). There would be no problem with page breaks.

Comment: @Bernard That's likely true, and would definitely fit better into the style of lists. Unfortunately, my coworkers have a workflow where they export a table from Excel, and want to do as little transformation on that as possible.

Answer (score 5):

Within a given table `X` always gets changed to `p{`*a fixed width*`}` where the width is determined in the beginning. As you have no `X` columns the algorithm will just give this width some arbitrary spurious small value.

So even if that `tabularx` had been set up correctly, the entries such as

```
\multicolumn{3}{X}{...}

\multicolumn{4}{X}{...}
```

will produce unwanted results, `X` here does not mean "span 3 or 4 columns and make a parbox that width" it means "span 3 or 4 columns and then centre a parbox of the X width in the middle of that span.

On top of this the `ltablex` package is a rather eccentric merger of longtable and `tabularx` and normally I'd just stick to `longtable`, or here, a list.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}

\renewcommand\theenumii{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{\theenumii.\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{\theenumii}
\setlength\leftmarginii  {2.2em}
\setlength\leftmarginiii {3em}

\listfiles

\begin{document}


\section*{A Heading}

\begin{enumerate}
   \item Foo
    \begin{enumerate}
     \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consequetum in farfarbar foobraz do congraftsh thing stuff wrap need enough to make you wrap
\end{enumerate}
    \item Bar
\begin{enumerate}
    \item More lorem ipsum, or stuff with numbers, that doesn't quite wrap as far end
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Random words words and more words in a fairly long line
    \item Other random words in a line
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\item Foo
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consequetum in farfarbar foobraz do congraftsh thing stuff wrap need enough to make you wrap
\end{enumerate}
 \item Bar
 \begin{enumerate}
    \item More lorem ipsum, or stuff with numbers, that doesn't quite wrap as far end
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Random words words and more words in a fairly long line
    \item Other random words in a line
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\item Foo
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consequetum in farfarbar foobraz do congraftsh thing stuff wrap need enough to make you wrap
\end{enumerate}
\item Bar
 \begin{enumerate}
    \item More lorem ipsum, or stuff with numbers, that doesn't quite wrap as far end
\end{enumerate}
   \item Foo
    \begin{enumerate}
     \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consequetum in farfarbar foobraz do congraftsh thing stuff wrap need enough to make you wrap
\end{enumerate}
    \item Bar
\begin{enumerate}
    \item More lorem ipsum, or stuff with numbers, that doesn't quite wrap as far end
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Random words words and more words in a fairly long line
    \item Other random words in a line
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\item Foo
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consequetum in farfarbar foobraz do congraftsh thing stuff wrap need enough to make you wrap
\end{enumerate}
 \item Bar
 \begin{enumerate}
    \item More lorem ipsum, or stuff with numbers, that doesn't quite wrap as far end
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Random words words and more words in a fairly long line
    \item Other random words in a line
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\item Foo
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consequetum in farfarbar foobraz do congraftsh thing stuff wrap need enough to make you wrap
\end{enumerate}
\item Bar
 \begin{enumerate}
    \item More lorem ipsum, or stuff with numbers, that doesn't quite wrap as far end
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 A list is really the only solution, especially when it's actually being numbered!

Comment: @Au101 and it avoids using two of my packages, which must be a good thing:-)